# PERMANOVA Design

Tags: anova, experiment-design, manova, environmental-data

My aim is to quantify temporal change in community composition by measuring community composition through time at several plots using randomly placed quadrats. The idea would be to repeat surveys at time intervals within each plot using random quadrats. The data would be analysed with permutational multivariate ANOVA.

The same plots would be measured at different time intervals but would this be considered a repeated measures design even though the quadrats are randomly placed within each plot at the different time intervals?

Comment: Not sure what program you intend to use for this, and therefore the current structure of your data. For this sort of sparse timing interval it would definitely still be considered repeated measures design given that that sort of design simply tries to account for the correlation between data points coming from the different measures of the same samples. If you organise your data into long/column format, you can specify the random time quadrant explicitely to account for the sparsity of the repeated measure, and use mixed model analysis to create and compare your model.

Comment: Thank you Mensen. I intend to use PERMANOVA for PRIMER 6. The data structure would be a matrix with species as columns and rows as quadrats indicating %cover. Then in terms of factors I would have "plot" and "time" as fixed factors (and orthogonal)and "quadrat" as a random factor nested within the plot and time interaction term. So effectively a mixed effects model. Hoping this is all correct?